# Color of status bar - Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, template10

I am develop an uwp app, and I am using template10. In template 10, there is an option to choose dark theme or light theme. When I choose dark theme, the status bar of Windows 10 Mobile is black (So far so good), but when I choose light theme, the status bar is white. I want the status bar to be black (as with the dark theme) when choosing the light theme. It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to set the color of the statusbar:

```
StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
```

Comment: Make sure to add a reference to the Windows Mobile Extensions for UWP and the above code will do it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not :(
Should be because I'm using Template10

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately it does not :( Should be because I'm using Template10

Template 10 should not influence the status bar. Please set the `BackgroundOpacity` to `1` for the status bar and test again.

```
StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundOpacity = 1;
```